# Failure to Add Layer from a WFS Provider QGIS 2.18.10

Tags: qgis, geoserver, wfs, ogc

I just installed QGIS 2.18.10. When I tried to add a layer from a WFS provider, it failed citing Bad Request as the reason. Exact message:

Falló la solicitud de red GML Getfeature con el error: Error downloading http://ide.igvsb.gob.ve/geoserver/escala250000/wfs/?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=1.0.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&TYPENAME=escala250000:ba_4189_orla_de_venezuela_250000_20161116&SRSNAME=EPSG:4189 - server replied: Forbidden

Answer (score 4):

It may be an issue with your network or a temporary issue with the server, it works for me.

I added `http://ide.igvsb.gob.ve/geoserver/escala250000/wfs/?VERSION=1.0.0` to as the WFS url and then added your layer and got this map:

[image]